# create table object from string

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have  markup with nested tables, rowspans and colspans in a string object. I would like to create an equivalent  .net object (table, grid, anything..) from it so that I can work on rows and columns of the table easily.

I am thinking when asp.net receive request from the browser with all the markup, .Net run time creates equivalent objects for us. Can I achieve the same thing programatically except that there is no table control on the page.

Or perhaps some sort of deserialization trick?

Any ideas?

Comment: Wrong.  The browser does not send any markup, and ASP.Net does not parse any HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. See SLaks comment.

You can however use HTMLAgilityPack, as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c).